# Can't Find Sdk folder for Android plug-in for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed Android Studio and working on it for the first time.

In Eclipse, the plug-in for Android Studio can't find path for Android sdk. There is a Path mentioned in Sdk Manager which is,

`C:\Users\Naqvi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

But when i go to My C drive i can't find that **"AppData"** folder which is mentioned in the Path. I searched for `sdk` folder on my computer but can't locate it any where. May be I have done any mistake during installation

Comment: There's an Eclipse plugin for Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you sounds so confusing, because **Eclipse** and **Android Studio** are two entirely separate IDEs for Android development and **sdk** is an Android Software Development Kit which is required to be used with the IDE to create Android development environment, it includes sample projects with source code, development tools, an emulator, and required libraries to build Android applications.

And as far as locating your **AppData** folder is concerned,
In windows OS, `AppData` folder is hidden by default, but you can still access it by typing the address of your location directly in you address bar, `C:\Users\Naqvi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Or you can enable the option to show hidden folder/files in your Windows.

If you are using Windows 7,

- Go to **My Computer**,
- click on **Organize** (under your address bar),
- Select **Folder and search options**,
- choose **View** tab.

There will be an option to **"show hidden files/folder and drives"** check it and Apply the settings. AppData folder will then be visible to you.